# Where is Open Console option in Intellij 12

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I am using Ultimate 12.1.4 on os/x 10.8.5 and I can not find "Open Console Here" (or the equivalent). I went through all the menu items several times as well as popup/context menu.

Comment: Same thing on Windows btw! This is really a little bit weird as PHPStorm (similar to IntelliJ, for PHP, built by the same company) comes with a perfect terminal by default since years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to open system terminal console in selected directory? There are sevelal options here:

1. External Tools -- (Settings | External Tools) -- you can execute any external command (exe/batch file/etc) you want. Make sure to set $FileDir$ as a tool working directory

   http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/external-tools.html
2. Command Line Tools -- "Tools | Run Command..." (you need to installe the Command Line Tools support plugin from the repository).

   http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/command-line-tool-support.html
   http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Command+Line+Tools
   http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/command-line-tools-in-phpstorm/
3. Terminal (available in upcoming IDEA v13) -- "Tools | Open Terminal..." (toolwindow should be pinned to the bottom of the screen by default)

   http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/09/built-in-local-terminal-in-phpstorm-7/
   http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/08/using-the-phpstorm-built-in-ssh-terminal-and-remote-ssh-external-tools/

Comment: Needs to be "open in directory of the selected file".

Comment: then external tool is your choice - when $FileDir$ is set as a tool working directory, running a tool from file right-click menu will open the console in the directory of the selected file